# C# DataTable Filter Fastest Way

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, linq, datatable

I have a datatable that include over 300.000 records and this equals over 2.000.000 words. I have an algorithm that get all words from each records and working well but I feel it is looks like little slow.

I want to speed up this program.

Program works like that;

1. Getting all records from database to datatable.
2. Loop datatable and get all words from each record.
3. For each word check new datatable contains that word, if not add to new datatable.

I search some titles about speed up this program.

1. using foreach or for ? (I think, there is no difference)
2. for checking datatable has words or not, using DataTable.Select() or Linq (actually Linq is faster)

But I worry about that check each word contains or make a word field primary (I don't know it works or not) or getting all words without checking and after all works using a distinc.

Can you give me some advice. Thanks.

```
        DataTable dtProducts = getProducts();
        bool contains;
        string[] keys;

        dt.Columns.Add("keyword", typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < dtProducts.Rows.Count; i++) //114040
        {
            keys = GetWords(dtProducts.Rows[i]["name"].ToString().Trim());

            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["keyword"] = key;

                contains = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(row => key == row.Field<string>("keyword"));

                if (!contains)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you use, it will make it easier to give you some tips.

Comment: Any reason you're using a `DataTable` to start with? It sounds like you should just use a `HashSet<string>` and add to it while reading from the database without a `DataTable` getting in the way.

Comment: Probably the most efficient way is to filter in the database and not to load all into memory first.

Comment: Does this table has one column and you extract the words by using `String.Split` or does it have multiple columns and each column represents one word? Tell us more about the schema and what you've tried, show some code.

Comment: It sounds like you need to get a unique list of words before you started, and then compare your list to whats in the database.. As you've not mentioned sanitizing your data before you compare it

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree that is one of the most optimal solutions, but it would be very nasty and you don't know what comes in between the words (;,-.~'" etc)

Comment: @JonSkeet I' m getting data from MS SQL database

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is not getting time to get all records into datatable. Problem is manipulate data.

Comment: I'm not sure how that comment is related to mine. You don't have to fetch via a `DataTable` just because you're using a SQL database...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way is to filter in the database and not to load all into memory first. But you can also improve performance by not loading all into a `DataTable` but if you use a `SqlDataReader` and a `HashSet<string>` instead:

```
private static readonly char[] WordSeparator = { ' ', '\t', ',', '.', ':' }; // to be continued
// ....


HashSet<string> allUniqueWords = new HashSet<string>();
using (var con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ColumnName FROM dbo.TableName", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        string[] words = rd.GetString(0).Split(WordSeparator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string word in words)
            allUniqueWords.Add(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://chrisbitting.com/2016/05/04/datatable-row-loop-csharp-performance-testing-linq-vs-select-vs-parallel-vs-for/) you can see that the fastest method is Parallel together with Linq:

```
        var sampleResults = from DataRow sampleRow in dataTableLocal.AsEnumerable()
                            where sampleRow.Field<string>("FirstColumn") == symbolName
                            select sampleRow;

        Parallel.ForEach(sampleResults, sampleRow =>
        {
            string sval = sampleRow["SecondColumn"].ToString();
        });
```

Comment: The basic principle is an idea giver.

Answer (score 0):

Your software will be exponentially slower because of the new added words and them not being sorted, so it will go through them all for every word in the records.

One basic thing to do is make your Datatable to a List and Insert the words into the List. In the beginning, it will be empty so you could just add the first word. Then you can [Binary Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh(v=vs.110).aspx) through the List for the given word and insert the new word in the sorted List if it's not found, and skip it if it's found.

This is a much more optimal solution for your software.

Comment: DataTable has any special feature like sorted ?

Comment: @ÖnderÖğretmen I did a quick search on Google and didn't find a function for Binary Search implemented into Datatable. Is there a reason why you explicitly want Datatable over List?

Comment: Why would you use binary search rather than a `HashSet<string>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Indeed, HashSet is faster, but it is probably more difficult for the Author to understand and use, so as I said in the Answer, "one basic thing to do is...". 2.000.000 is not a huge number so that a hashset would be mandatory. The hash function has a very important role in using the hashset.

Comment: It's *much* easier to use than creating a list, sorting it and then using `BinarySearch`... it's also significantly faster. 2 million entries is enough that you really want to be O(1) rather than O(log n) for each insert.

Answer (score 0):

Put each word as a key into a dictionary and assign the created table reference for a quick search to make a decision. Design the key to your needs as a virtual index.